# Does putting a date format on a date field make a difference in vba?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've been looking and how people write code and was wondering if placing a format on a date field makes a difference. For example I saw this `Format(EndDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")` in a query but EndDate is defined as a Date field in the Table.

What are the benefits and problems that may arise for doing this?

```
strEDate = "#" & Format(EndDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"

strHSurg = "SELECT TOP 1 [Health Surcharge]FROM tblTax WHERE [Effective Date] <= strEDate " ORDER BY [Effective Date] DESC;"
```

If EndDate is a Date field couldn't you have the query like this

```
strHSurg = "SELECT TOP 1 [Health Surcharge]FROM tblTax WHERE [Effective Date] <= " & EDate & " ORDER BY [Effective Date] DESC;"
```

Does it matter? Or is it done so if the database is moved to a computer with the dd/mm/yyyy format the formulas will not be affected?

Comment: A format is to create a string for display or to concatenate in SQL. In VBA you will always use the Date data type, never text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format takes a `Date` variable/field and converts it to `String`. The difference between the two is far more than visuals. You cannot perform date type functions (like `DateAdd`) on a String or String functions (like `Replace`) on a `Date`.

I generally use the Format function when I am adding the date to a string. That can be a string the user will see (for example in a report header you can have different outputs like "Total Sales for 1/1/2020" or "Total Sales for January 1, 2020") or when generating an SQL query string to make sure the expected date format is what Access expects and avoid localization issues.

In every case the data is kept as a `Date` data type. I never store date data as `String`.

Comment: So setting the format to a date will not affect the SQL query no matter what the system date format is, right?

Comment: If you are building an SQL query string and you use `Format` to make sure the date is properly formatted for what MS Access queries expect, that does make the system date format irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I like to format my dates using VBA because you never know what the formatting of a field may be. If there is a specific date format on the field you are writing to then the field format overrides the format assigned by VBA. Just like typing in the field. You can enter the data in any format, the field formatting will coalesce the data in to it's stated format.

To be safe, use the same format in VBA that you would expect the field to have.